# Export comma-separated text file to csv and maintain leading zeros

Tags: powershell, csv

I have 3 .txt files that each need to be converted into .csv files.  Each file has 12 columns and some of these columns have data with leading zeroes.  These zeroes need to remain.  Is there a way through PowerShell to write a loop that will export each of these to a .csv and maintain the leading zeros?

The closest thing I could do was to export them one at a time, but this doesn't maintain the trailing zeros that I need.

```psh
Import-Csv C:\AcctsLog.txt  -Delimiter ";" | Export-Csv C:\AcctsLog.csv
```

A sample line would be something like:

```
Joe Smith;1933 Test Lane;Apt 34;Los Angeles;CA;90003-3444;0000000023;0002;New Car;SmithJoe@yahoo.com;00934200034006700213;0000666666
```

Comment: Can you provide a few sample lines from your file?

Comment: Sample line added...sorry for the poor formatting.

Comment: Does the file have a header row?

Comment: No, it doesn't have a header row.

Comment: To convert a `.txt` to a `.csv`, simply change the file extension. I assume you are opening the `.csv` in Excel? It's Excel that is hiding the zeros. There's nothing wrong with your CSV file

Answer (score 1):

See if this works with your data:

```
Import-Csv C:\AcctsLog.txt -Delimiter ';' -Header (1..12) | 
ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | select -Skip 1 |
Set-Content C:\AcctsLog.csv
```

Comment: For what it's worth I don't see any trailing zeroes in the sample data that you posted. Also, when you say that the trailing zeroes are gone, how are you verifying that? Are you opening the file in a program. I would also point out that your question is initially about leading zeroes not trailing ones.

Comment: Sorry...I meant leading zeros.  I'm opening the file in Excel and the leading zeros are gone.

Comment: @Chris That's because Excel imports the fields as numbers. To preserve leading zeroes in Excel you need to either format the columns accordingly or import the columns as text.

Comment: @Chris Open it in notepad to verify. Excel might be removing them since it would treat it as a number

Comment: Excel by default strips them out. You have to tell it to treat the column as text.

Answer (score 0):

If you explicitly want it to include the leading 0's in Excel you would have to save it as an Excel file (otherwise Excel strips leading zeros off values that it interprets as numbers when opening a CSV). You could paste the data into Excel after formatting the cells as Text, then save the files as excel files. But if you want CSV files then go with mjolinor's answer since it produces CSV files with the leading zeros, exactly like you asked for.

To work with Excel you have to create an Excel ComObject. Then you can get the content of your file, replace the semicolons with tabs, pipe to `Clip`, and paste right into Excel (after creating a workbook and formatting the 12 columns that you need). Should be pretty simple:

```psh
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.Visible = $true
$FileList = @("C:\Temp\AcctsLog.txt","C:\Temp\SecondFile.txt","C:\Temp\ThirdFile.txt")

ForEach($File in $FileList){
    [void]$Excel.Workbooks.Add()
    $Excel.ActiveSheet.Range("A:L").NumberFormat = '@'
    (Get-Content $File) -replace ';', "`t" | Clip
    $Excel.ActiveSheet.Paste()
    $Excel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(($File -replace "txt$","xlsx"))
    $Excel.ActiveWorkbook.Close($false)
}

$Excel.Quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to maintain the leading zeroes in Excel.

Simply add this to the cell and type whatever value you need and the zeroes will be retained

For ex:  If I want 0000000023

Type into a cell  **'0000000023**

That ' symbol seems to retain the zeroes as long as you type it before the values.